# What is a difference between 'Operating System' and 'Command Shell'?

Tags: operating-system

What is a difference between 'Operating System' and 'Command Shell'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell and an OS are different. Let me explain.

An operating system is a program initiated by either the BIOS or EFI. The OS controls the very low-level aspects of the hardware and provides APIs to software to use them. OSes are usually a collection of a kernel and a bunch of applications. Examples of OSes are Window$, Mac OS X, UNIX, Ubuntu, Solaris. Note that Linux is **not** an OS, but rather a kernel, which is the most important part of an OS.

A shell is an application that runs on the OS and provides the **user interface** to the OS. Examples of shells are bash, sh, cmd.exe and windowserver.app.

Usually an OS comes packed with one or more shells.

Comment: @magicyoung it doesn't have to be, but most user-oriented OSes have one. Examples that don't have a shell are microcontrollers, Wii Remote, computer diplays, cars and other embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Actually shell is just like any program, which takes uses input (commands) and execute them.

> ps aux | grep bash

will give you all the shell processes running on your computer (assuming you are using bash).

Check the [code here](http://insready.com/simple-shell) for a simple implementation of a shell. You can compile it and run it. That will a new shell for you.