# Programmable strings in Debian GNOME Terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, debian, gnome

I like GNOME Terminal very much. I'd like to know if it has the possibility to remap some (Ctrl+Function) keys to send some strings to the terminal. I know I can do it on the OS level, but I'd rather that it be localized. If GNOME Terminal doesn't have that possibility, I'll have to switch to xterm (it seems xterm can do that), but I'd rather not. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify: the question appears to be asking if gnome-terminal supports escape sequences which allow an application to change key-bindings.  To that, the answer is "no".

The term "localized" generally refers to something different: the customization of an application to different locales.  For example, see [What is Localization and How to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496899/what-is-localization-and-how-to-use-it)

Likewise, "OS level" (operating system level) is different from gnome-terminal's "Keyboard shortcuts" dialog in two respects:

- The dialog is a GUI application, outside the actual terminal emulation.
- Operating systems are a different level from applications (see for example [What is a difference between 'Operating System' and 'Command Shell'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218978/what-is-a-difference-between-operating-system-and-command-shell))

Comment: It seems you didn't quite understand my question, but it doesn't matter - there is no support for what I want.

Comment: I was clarifying the question, since (lacking further information) "localized" is normally used in a different sense.  But I answered what seems to be your question in the first sentence :-)